# 2D array in android

Tags: android, arrays, 2d

I am trying to run this code in android using eclips IDE.

---

```
int maxrow=0;

int label=10;

int[][] relations=new int[500][200];

make2dzero(relations,500,200); //initialized every element with 0.

relations[maxrow][0]=label;
```

---

The last line i.e `relations[maxrow][0]=label;` is throwing an array out of bound exception. If i use `relations[0][0]=label;` then the code runs fine.
Does any one know what is wrong with this piece of code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  `maxrow` is greater than or equal to 500 at the point in which you call `relations[maxrow][0] = label;`

Check where you increment `maxrow` and make sure it doesn't go beyond or equal to your limit, 500.

Comment: indeed that was the case. the value of maxrow was going beyond 500. Since i am not using a debugger, i thought something else was causing this problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

if `relations[maxrow][0]=label;` fails, but `relations[0][0]=label;` works, then `maxrow` is not 0. Try printing out the value of `maxrow` and seeing what it is.

My guess is you have snipped out the piece of the code that does something like reset the value of `maxrow`, or it's accidentally being set inside your initialization method there.

For the record, you don't need to initialize your values to 0. They're already set to 0 by default. You'd only need that if you were initializing them to a non-zero value.

Superior intializer for OP:

```
/**
 * Initialize a 2d int array to any single value
 * The array does not need to be rectangular.
 * Null rows in the 2d array are skipped (code exists to initialize them to empty.)
 * @param arr the array to modify to contain all single values
 * @param value the value to set to all elements of arr
 */
static void initializeArray(final int[][] arr, final int value) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == null) continue; // perhaps it wasn't initialized
        /* optional error handling
        if(arr[i] == null) {
            arr[i] = new int[0];
            continue;
        }
        */
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) arr[i][j] = value;
    }
}
```

Examples for Oceanblue:

```
// works, arrays as OP is working with
class Oceanblue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = new int[30][50];
        System.out.println(arr[4][6]); // should be 0
    }
}
```

Results of the this one:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\glow\My Documents>javac Oceanblue.java

C:\Documents and Settings\glow\My Documents>java Oceanblue
0
```

This doesn't work:

```
// doesn't work for local variables that aren't arrays
class Oceanblue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int test;
        test++; // bombs
        System.out.println(test); // should be 1, but line above bombed
    }
}
```

Result, as you mentioned

```
C:\Documents and Settings\glow\My Documents>javac Oceanblue.java
Oceanblue.java:4: variable test might not have been initialized
        test++; // bombs
        ^
1 error
```

Comment: @glowcoder: "For the record, you don't need to initialize your values to 0. They're already set to 0 by default. You'd only need that if you were initializing them to a non-zero value."  True, but you cannot use them without initializing them if they are local variables (as opposed to class variables).

Comment: @Oceanblue yes you can. I'll update with example. edit: updated.

Comment: Initializing your variables to 0 is a carryover from C where when you allocated memory, you didn't know what you might have. So you were forced to 0 it out. Java does that for you on allocation.

Comment: @Downvoter, I'd like to know how this post could be improved if you feel it's not useful. Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks for the info about 0 initialization. you are right. i had the same idea in my mind that without initialization, there is some garbage value present in the memory.

Comment: Sure thing. I'd also like to point out that you don't need to pass in the length and width of the array. I could edit in a superior version of that. edit: updated.

Answer (score 0):

Something, somewhere is obviously updating *maxrow*. Try searching on *maxrow* in your code.